# Spring order of @component creation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In what order the @Component classes will be created in spring. is it @configuration annotated class that will be created first ?? Can we specify the order of creation ??

Answer (score 1):

`@Component` and `@Configuration` are different types of annotations.

`@Component` and similar annotations (`@Service`, `@Repository`, etc. ) and its JSR-330 counterpart and allow you to declare beans that are to be picked up by autoscanning with `<context:component-scan/>` or `@ComponentScan` they register the bean definition for the classes, so they are roughly equivalent to declaring the specified beans with the `<bean ... />` tag in XML. This bean types will adhere to the standard proxy creation policies.

`@Configuration` annotation was designed as the replacement of the XML configuration file. To create `@Configuration` annotated beans, Spring will always use CGLIB to subclass the `@Configuration` annotated class, overriding its `@Bean` annotated method to replace it with the bean lookup method to make singleton beans to be created only once. Despite that, `@Configuration` annotated classes are still able to use annotated(`@Autowired`, `@Inject` etc.) fields and properties to request beans (and even other `@Configuration` annotated beans too) from the container.

Now answer to your question, you have to annotate the class with `@Configuration` and then with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.*" })` and you can't specify the order of creation.

Comment: Actually `@Configuration`, like `@Service` is also a `@Component` and as such will also be detected when doing component scans.

Comment: @Arpit and M. Deinum :  thanks for the replies. As Denuim said Configuration is also a Component that will be detected at component scan.  Actually my requirement is  i  want to declare all my application specific configuration data in Configuration class (by reading the values from properties file ) and i want to make all other components use this configuration data . So i want this Configuration class to be loaded first all the time and then all other components . So just want confirm again is  that we can't specify the order of creation ?